# fontFamily "lonicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, icons

My react native project all of a sudden stopped loading all vector icons with this error

```
fontFamily "Material Design Icons"     is not a system font and has not been      loaded through Font.loadAsync.
```

And i have no idea what could be causing it.

I have deleted node_modules and ran ‘npm install’ still dose not load icons. This is how icons look like in my app

[image]

Please what else do i do to fix this